# How do I get all text boxes within a given div based on its class name?

Tags: jquery, textbox, jquery-chosen

This is really slowing down my progress this morning. Any help would be incredible. Here's my code that I'm using to try to get each text box:

```
$('.contactInfo input[type="text"]').each(function () { 

});
```

The above code works but it keeps grabbing select boxes as well. I've tried using a colon in between the class name and input type identifier as well as a number of other ways to get each text box (:input, :text, type=text, etc.). Forgive my styling on here as I'm completely new to asking questions and haven't gotten the hang of the formatting.
**Note: `.contactInfo` is a class assigned to the div that contains the text boxes I want to get. Also, I'm using the chosen jquery plugin to style my select boxes as well. This may or may not have anything to do with my issue, just wanted to let you all know.**
Thanks in advance for anything you guys can help me with!
**Update: I've tried every solution listed here. Each one grabs the select box, however, it doesn't return its id. So, I'm just using a workaround that checks if its id is null so that I can skip it during the iterations. I really appreciate each of you for your input! Thanks!**

Comment: It'd be better if you show your html.

Comment: `$('input.contactInfo[type="text"]').each(function () {
});`

Comment: what do plan to do with textboxes inside the div?

Comment: That shouldn't pick up the select boxes - I did a quick test: http://jsfiddle.net/tTSxV/ I can only figure there is something wrong with your HTML.

Comment: Your code works for me as is...  http://jsfiddle.net/HKVuf/ - but @nekaab has a better selector below.

Comment: @pXL I'm pretty sure my HTML is ok, I'm certain it's my jquery that isn't correct.

Comment: @Learner I'm validating the information using my own markup so that I can pass it to the server.

Answer (score 7):

See http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/:

`$('.contactInfo input:text')`

Comment: You don't even need `input:text`, it's redundant.  `:text` selects for inputs of type text.

Comment: @SurrealDreams: However, adding `input` makes it faster.  See the docs.

Comment: I hadn't caught on about the :pseudoselectors, thanks for pointing that out to me.  `input:text` is the better way to go.  Thanks, @SLaks.

Comment: If you are looking for performance, better would be to use `input[type=text]` then

Answer (score 6):

```
$(".contactInfo").find("input[type=text]")
```

This should find all the textboxes within that div (.contactInfo). Another thing to note is that find() method is going to be much faster than context selectors.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(".contactInfo").children("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    //Do stuff here
});
```